# If a page has not been requested, the page will be refreshed or the route will be redirected. How to solve it?

Tags: request, frontend, router

In the front-end development, when the background data has not returned to the foreground, the page is refreshed and the latter route jumps. How should this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when you are calling a backend API from frontend, and you don't know when you will recieve the response.In that case you show the user spinner before redirecting to the next page which depends on the API response.

You should conditionally render the component which requires the data from your api as props.
Once you receive the data from the API you can update the state of hasReceivedData  to true.

```
hasReceivedData ? <Component> : '<Spinner>'
```